# IOS App memory usage standards

Tags: ios, performance, testing, swift3, instruments

### Hi there,

#### Question

I am very new to iOS development and monitoring the stats of an app. Yesterday I was watching instruments and seen that the memory usage of my app in idle was between 7 to 9 MB.

My guess is that this is much for a app just being idle but then again, I m new and don't know if this a sort of standard.

Can someone explain me with this information that how much memory it generally use in idle state?

#### Leaks

I have checked for the memory leakage but there are no leaks.

Comment: you have to visit https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html

Comment: I have ~40mb memory usage for empty app with one view controller from templates on iPhone7. It's kinda OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

No, that doesn't strike me as much memory usage. Take an empty new project (Single View template), for example. That already takes up about 6 MB. Whether it's in background or foreground.
IIRC the iPhone 6 has 1 GB of actual RAM, but the way the architecture works makes the memory less an impact on performance on e.g. desktop systems. With only 7 MB of using that your app doesn't even need to be swapped unless the user has literally dozens of other, more hungry apps running.

Basically, you're hardly above the minimum that an app will consume just for displaying a white screen...

Comment: Gero, thanks for the response. the app was in idle on the foreground.. i now got a clearer view.. dumb of me not testing it with a clean project first!

Comment: @iDesigns You're welcome. And don't worry, we all started at some point. The question shows you're at least considering these things. My tip would be to keep that in the back of your head while continuing to develop. Don't just hack stuff together and be done with it, follow the best practices and recommendations in the Apple frameworks. Then, memory usually isn't an issue. If it becomes, the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is often a good place to start. You might then also check https://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks. It's older, but still valuable imo.

Comment: Thank you man positive feedback is always something thats keeps me going so thanks for that..

Answer (score 19):

If you mean that your application was in the foreground but you weren't doing anything your memory footprint is acceptable (in fact it is very low).

If you are targeting iOS 10 the lowest memory capability mobile device your app will be run on will be 512mb of RAM (iPhone 4s). The given "point of worry" for memory usage for this device would be around the ~170 / 180mb range.

Here are some crash stats for devices (RAM Usage @ Crash / Total Memory Limit of device):

iPad1: 127MB/256MB/49%

iPad2: 275MB/512MB/53%

iPad3: 645MB/1024MB/62%

iPad4: 585MB/1024MB/57% (iOS 8.1)

iPad Mini 1st Generation: 297MB/512MB/58%

iPad Mini retina: 696MB/1024MB/68% (iOS 7.1)

iPad Air: 697MB/1024MB/68%

iPad Air 2: 1195MB/2048MB/58% (iOS 8.x)

iPad Pro 12.9: 3064MB/3981MB/77% (iOS 9.3.2)

iPad Pro 9.7": 1395MB/1971MB/71% (iOS 10.0.2 (14A456))

iPod touch 4th gen: 130MB/256MB/51% (iOS 6.1.1)

iPod touch 5th gen: 286MB/512MB/56% (iOS 7.0)

iPhone4: 325MB/512MB/63%

iPhone4S: 286MB/512MB/56%

iPhone5: 645MB/1024MB/62%

iPhone5S: 646MB/1024MB/63%

iPhone6: 645MB/1024MB/62% (iOS 8.x)

iPhone6+: 645MB/1024MB/62% (iOS 8.x)

iPhone6s: 1396MB/2048MB/68% (iOS 9.2)

iPhone6s+: 1195MB/2048MB/58% (theoretical, untested)

iPhoneSE: 1395MB/2048MB/69% (iOS 9.3)

iPhone7+: 2040MB/3072MB/66% (iOS 10.2.1)

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it, basically. Kudos for listing the actual RAM of all those devices! Neato!

Comment: thanks for the list.. very handy!